# Sharing changes to a post (preview changes) with another user

Tags: plugin-development, previews

We would like to be able to share changes to an existing post with other wp users without saving the changes (making them live). A nounce currently makes it impossible to share a previewed post.

Is there a way around this? a plugin maybe? If not, what would be a good approach if I where to develop a plugin with this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know of a plugin but a good approach would be:

1. to crate a custom post type (shared_revisions).
2. add a metabox to post edit screen which will have an option to save the post changes
   as a sheared_revision and store the original post id as postmeta of the sheared_revision post.
3. add a metabox to your sheared_revision edit screen which will have
   an option to overwrite the original post.

   Hope this make sense.

Comment: Yes this makes perfect sense. Ideally the Edit Post interface would include new buttons, one that creates the shared_revision and one that publishes it. Also a post that has a shared_revision should not be editable, nor should it be possible to create second shared_revision. Thanks!